# How to make functions to return a json string on calling them in php?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I made the following script but I want that each script should echo the `json_encode` array only when I call the function. When I tried defining the function, and then calling it, it displayed nothing. It is working if the scripts are not made in the functions. How do I make different functions and then call different functions according to my usage?

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', '0');
error_reporting(0);
require_once("include/db.php");
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

$regno ='14ASDFJ234';
$password = '0';
$name = 'EASPORTS';
$priority = 0;

//fetch priority
$query = "SELECT priority FROM users WHERE regno='{$regno}' AND pass='{$password}' LIMIT 1";
$res = mysql_query($query, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
$found = mysql_fetch_array($res);

if($found)
{
    $priority=$found['priority'];               
}

//echo $priority;
echo 'news feed : <br> '
$sql = "SELECT  * FROM newsfeed";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $details[] = array(
        'name' => $row['name'],
        'feed' => $row['feed']         
    );
}   

echo json_encode($details);

// announcement details...
echo "<br> Announcement details: <br>";

$sql1 = "SELECT  * FROM announcements WHERE name = '$name'";
$result1 = mysql_query($sql1,$conn) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {

    $details1[] = array(
        'name' => $row1['name'],
        'pname' => $row1['pname'],
        'date' => $row1['date'],
        'time' => $row1['time'],
        'status' => $row1['status']       
    );
}   

echo json_encode($details1);

//events script...

?>
```

Comment: I don't see any function in your code. You are returning json_encoded arrays

Comment: How you calling the script? If you call the script by POST or GET request, it will execute the full script, not any function. maybe for this reason the script is giving you result but the function is not.. though there is no function defined here now. If you share your function version of the code, that will be easy to spot the problem. Also please share how you calling the script.

Comment: @KhanShahrukh, each echo json_encode() should be in function.. for example echoing $details will be one function and echoing $details1 would be a different function. Now, all the arrays are echoed. but i want to make functions . say function announcement() just echoes the $details1. So how to declare, define and use function.?

Comment: Improved formatting for readability. Please add the details from your comment to the question by editing it.

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this

```
public function somefunction()
{
        $query = "SELECT priority FROM users WHERE regno='{$regno}' AND pass='{$password}' LIMIT 1";
    $res = mysql_query($query, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
    $found = mysql_fetch_array($res);
    if($found)
    {
            $priority=$found['priority'];


        }

//echo $priority;
echo 'news feed : <br> '
$sql="SELECT  * FROM newsfeed";
$result=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {



        $details[] = array(
            'name' => $row['name'],
            'feed' => $row['feed']

        );
        }   
        echo json_encode($details);
}
```

now when you call somefunction() you will get json encoded array as result